# Simplification of a sum in nuclear physics

Tags: homework-and-exercises, nuclear-physics

How can I prove that $$\sum_{kk'>0,k\ne{k'}}u_kv_ku_{k'}v_{k'}+\sum_{k>0}v_k^2=(\sum_{k>0}u_kv_k)^2+\sum_{k>0}v_k^4~?$$

Comment: How can you get a fourth power?

Comment: Hi, welcome to Physics SE. What are the $u$s & $v$s? If they're dimensionful, the equation as stated is incorrect. Perhaps $\sum_{k>0}v_k^2$ should be squared, like $\sum_{k>0}u_kv_k$?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.